# Can binarysearch be used for checking primality?

Tags: java, performance, primes, binary-search

I wonder if binary search can be used to check whether a number is prime , Since the real question is can I find a number which is divisble other than the number itself and 1, and therefore I can imagine looking through an array of ordered integers from 2 to i/2 (i being a number being checked).......

Comment: I've never heard of such an algorithm. So my guess is no.

Comment: On first sight this makes little to no sense. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: BTW, if you're looking for a divisor of i, the candidates would be 2 through sqrt(i), not 2 through i/2

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Although a larger candidate set does not do any harm - besides slowing down the processing.

Comment: How is what you are describing any different than the brute force method?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously not.

Binary search is a method of dividing the interval to two (almost) equal parts and decide which one contains the search value.

Testing any number to see whether it is a divisor doesn't tell you anything about which interval to choose.

Comment: I see , I only thought there must be some kind of way of choosing an interval but I guess not

Comment: @M.K. If there was some useful* method to choose the interval (as far as I know, no one has proven the nonexistence of such a method), then why could not this method be applied to the internal 2,sqrt(n) - solving the problem in one step.  (*There are plenty of useless methods such as brute force to choose the interval.)